# Setting Atlasboard theme for a single dashboard

Tags: themes, dashboard, atlasboard

When configuration themes in Atlasboard, I know you can set the global theme in `config/theming.js`, but is there a way to have a single dashboard use a different theme than the others?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried but look like you could do it form version 1.0. Refer to "Theming support" in  [Atlasboard overview](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/atlasboard/overview). Following instructions may work

Define your theme name in {yourcurrentwallboard}

```
{yourcurrentwallboard}/themes/{themename}/variables.styl
```

Set the defined theme for {yourcurrentwallboard}

```
{yourwallboard}/config/theming.js

module.exports = {
  theme: '{themename}'
};
```